# How to select and join more than 2 tables in oracle?

Tags: oracle, join, select, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have an oracle database design as shown in the picture.
my question, how can i display id_produk of tb_produk by using select with condition :

```
produk_gaya.id_ghidup = wajah_gaya.id_ghidup
produk_konsern.id_konsern = wajah_konsern.id_konsern
produk_tipe.id_tipe = tb_wajah.id_tipe
```

Please help, thank you
[image of database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1nge.jpg)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired output for this data, your current code and description of what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to just want to join the tables along the primary and foreign key relationships (you can skip `tb_hidup` as `produk_gaya` and `wajah_gaya` both have foreign-key relationship to the same primary key; similar for `tb_konsern` and `tb_type`):

```sql
SELECT p.id_produk
FROM   tb_produk p
       INNER JOIN produk_gaya pg    ON p.id_produk = pg.id_produk
       INNER JOIN wajah_gaya wg     ON pg.id_ghidup = wg.id_ghidup
       INNER JOIN produk_konsern pk ON p.id_produk = pk.id_produk
       INNER JOIN wajah_konsern wk  ON pk.id_konsern = wk.id_konsern
       INNER JOIN produk_tipe pt    ON p.id_produk = pt.id_produk
       INNER JOIN tb_wajah w        ON pt.id_tipe = tb_wajah.id_tipe
```

Comment: How do I find out the correct id_produk for tb_wajah with the same condition at the beginning?

Comment: @DevyPutriNatalie You have not provided any example data or an explanation of what you expect to find or how to determine what is "correct". If you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70053632/edit) your question to show that then maybe we can answer that question; until then, the query I gave finds all the `id_produk` for `tb_wajah` that matches the conditions in the question.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have tried the query and it works fine.